# Null check String.ToLower in Linq Where expression

Tags: c#, linq, null

I have this method

```
private IList<Order> FilterOrders(string filterText)
{
    string filterTextLowerCase = filterText.ToLower();
    var filtered = _orders.Where(order =>
        order.OrderIdFullOrderNumber.ToLower().Contains(filterTextLowerCase) ||
        order.Name.ToLower().Contains(filterTextLowerCase) ||
        order.Status.ToLower().Contains(filterTextLowerCase) ||
        order.TimeRemaining.ToLower().Contains(filterTextLowerCase) ||
        order.Address.ToLower().Contains(filterTextLowerCase) ||
        order.City.ToLower().Contains(filterTextLowerCase) ||
        order.State.Abbrev.ToLower().Contains(filterTextLowerCase) ||
        order.PostalCode.ToLower().Contains(filterTextLowerCase)).ToList();
    return filtered;
}
```

As you can see there's a possible nullreference exception in properties, what would be the best way to check for null in this Where expression?

Comment: Use null conditional operator i.e `?.ToLower()`

Comment: Well which of those properties might be null? And what is the type of `_orders`?

Comment: Don't convert to lowercase.  Use a string comparer.

Comment: @RobertMcKee I agree about that. However, a null check would still be relevant in that case.

Comment: I agree with the string comparer. Will change as well accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I couldn't use C# 6.0 features at this point.

I ended up creating an extension method to filter the list, comparing with another extension method, Contains, that accepts a StringComparison parameter as suggested from @robert-mckee and demonstrated from @jeppe-stig-nielsen.

```
public static IList<Order> FilterOrders(this IList<Order> orders, string filterText)
        {
            var filtered = orders.Where(order =>
                order.OrderIdFullOrderNumber.Contains(filterText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                order.Name.Contains(filterText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                order.Status.Contains(filterText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                order.TimeRemaining.Contains(filterText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                order.Address.Contains(filterText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                order.City.Contains(filterText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                order.State.Abbrev.Contains(filterText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                order.PostalCode.Contains(filterText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
            return filtered;
        }

public static bool Contains(this string source, string value, StringComparison comparison)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return source.IndexOf(value, comparison) >= 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 22):

If you are using C# 6 you can add a `?.` null check operator before accessing the objects properties or methods : `order?.State?.ToLower()....`

See [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2015/06/05/c.net-little-wonders-null-conditional-operator-in-c-6.aspx) for more info on the new null check operator.

If you are using a lower version you have to have to add an additional null check to each where clause : `.Where(order => (order.State != null && order.State.ToLower()....)`

Comment: Yes, this is one of the many nice language features of C# 6.0. Otherwise, your best bet is to go with an extension to perform the ToLower() in a safe way.

Comment: Note that `bool?` has no `||` operator. However, the `|` operator [works as expected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) here, at least if you only accept `true` afterward.

Comment: I think the C# 6.0 null check operator is the most elegant way to go.

Answer (score 10):

Add this extension method:

```
public static string NullSafeToLower(this string s)
{
    if (s == null)
    {
        s = string.Empty;
    }
    return s.ToLower();
}
```

Then replace calls to "ToLower" with calls to "NullSafeToLower."

Answer (score 7):

Even though the question's already answered, another alternative would be something like:

`var myVar = orders.Where(o => (o.SomeProperty ?? "").ToLower() == "someValue");`

While this isn't as pretty, if you only need it once or twice, this probably isn't as "heavy" as an extension method is, but if you need to do this a lot (as in your example) then one of the extension methods listed as answers will serve you better.

For reference, I've had to do this because the build environment I was working on at the time didn't support C# 6.0 yet.  It's good to have fallback tricks in case you're working in a slow-to-adopt environment (it happens!).  Just wanted to throw this out there. :)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is pretty or ugly. It does create a temporary array for each order, but it avoids a lot of repetition.

```
List<Order> FilterOrders(string filterText)
{
  return _orders.Where(order =>
    new[] {
    order.OrderIdFullOrderNumber,
    order.Name,
    order.Status,
    order.TimeRemaining,
    order.Address,
    order.City,
    order.State,
    order.PostalCode,
    }.Any(str => str != null
    && str.IndexOf(filterText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I could swear this used to work, but now I just get `The translation of String.IndexOf to SQL does not support versions with a StringComparison argument.` with LINQ over SQL and `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 IndexOf(System.String, System.StringComparison)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` with LINQ over EF.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following extension method.

```
public static class StringHelper
{
    public static string SafeToLower(this string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        return value.ToLower();
    }
}
```

Your code would then become the following.

```
private IList<Order> FilterOrders(string filterText)
{
    string filterTextLowerCase = filterText.ToLower();
    var filtered = _orders.Where(order =>
        order.OrderIdFullOrderNumber.SafeToLower().Contains(filterTextLowerCase) ||
        order.Name.SafeToLower().Contains(filterTextLowerCase) ||
        order.Status.SafeToLower().Contains(filterTextLowerCase) ||
        order.TimeRemaining.SafeToLower().Contains(filterTextLowerCase) ||
        order.Address.SafeToLower().Contains(filterTextLowerCase) ||
        order.City.SafeToLower().Contains(filterTextLowerCase) ||
        order.State.Abbrev.SafeToLower().Contains(filterTextLowerCase) ||
        order.PostalCode.SafeToLower().Contains(filterTextLowerCase)).ToList();
    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: Your safe method will throw null reference exception if string is null. Because calling like `item.something` requires reference

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, Extension methods don't cause compiler-generated NREs from the callee being null.

Comment: Nope. Static methods does not cause NRE. When you use `this` it requires reference for extention calls. @chris

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, You can see it work [here](http://rextester.com/TRZ25771). Note that when I commented, `SafeToLower` was still an extension method. The answer would have worked fine before, though it's for this reason (these back-and-forth comments) that I would hesitate to use such an extension method.

Comment: Chris, you are correct here. I just tested this in a console app and it does not in fact cause a NRE.

Comment: @chris sorry if I was wrong i will ckeck this later. Btw thanks for the inform.

Comment: The extension method is a good option indeed, it was the first thing I've thought.