# How to give property name in string in lambda expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I want to write a query in .net core using ef. Now the issue is, I am getting the property name in parameter and I want to put condition on that property i.e

```
  public IQueryable<MyModel> Generate(string property, IQueryable<MyModel> query)
  {
    query = query.Where(a => a.property.ToLower() != null);
  }
```

MyModel:

```
public string Property1 { get; set; }
public string Property2 { get; set; }
public string Property3 { get; set; }
```

Method Calling:

```
var query = Generate(MyModel.Property2, query);
```

I know this is possible using reflection but that has some performance impacts. So is there any better approach?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Also this will not work `property.ToLower() != null`, `ToLower()` never returns `null`.

Comment: Are you passing `MyModel.Property2` or `nameof(MyModel.Property2)`? `MyModel.Property2` does not contain property name, it contain property value...

Comment: Simply, no. You must use reflection. That is the only way to take a string and somehow access a real property via that. There's ways you can encapsulate the logic, as some of the answers below do, but ultimately, you're still using reflection.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use `Func<MyModel, string>` as param?

```
public IQueryable<MyModel> Generate(Func<MyModel, string> propertySelector, IQueryable<MyModel> query)
{
   query = query.Where(a => propertySelctor(a).ToLower() != null);
}
```

And use like:

```
var query = Generate(m => m.Property2, query);
```

Comment: Whats the idea behind lowering string's case and checking if it's not null?

Comment: I think, I wrote the question wrongly. The issue is I don't exactly which property I need to pass in Generate(m => m.Property2, query); I have only string value that I can pass. It might be Property1 or Property2 or Property3. Like Generate("property3", query);

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT after question clarification:**

You could implement a generic extension method for IQueryable where the clause is dynamically built:

```
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TModel> WhereNotNull<TModel>(this IQueryable<TModel> query, string propertyName)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "x");
        var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
        var comparison = Expression.NotEqual(body, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(object)));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(comparison, parameter);
        return query.Where(lambda);
    }
}
```

Call it like:

```
query = query.WhereNotNull(nameof(MyModel.Property1));
```

or

```
query = query.WhereNotNull("Property1");
```

**EDIT after request for null or whitespace check on strings:**

Example of calling `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` on string properties:

```
public static IQueryable<TModel> WhereNotNull<TModel>(this IQueryable<TModel> query, string propertyName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "x");
    var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
    Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> lambda = null;
    if (body.Type == typeof(string))
    {
        var methodCall = Expression.Call(typeof(string), nameof(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace), null, body);
        var nullOrWhiteSpaceComparison = Expression.Not(methodCall);
        lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(nullOrWhiteSpaceComparison, parameter);
    }
    else
    {
        var nullComparison = Expression.NotEqual(body, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(object)));
        lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(nullComparison, parameter);
    }
    return query.Where(lambda);
    }
```

If you (in some other context) want to combine multiple expressions you may use `Expression.And(Expression left, Expression right)` or `Expression.Or(Expression left, Expression right)`. Pass the unary/binary expression as parameters left and right.

Comment: The issue is I don't exactly which property I need to pass in Generate(m => m.Property2, query); I have only string value that I can pass. It might be Property1 or Property2 or Property3. Like Generate("property3", query)

Comment: If you are using C# 6 there is no need to create custom extension for null checking. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212234/null-check-string-tolower-in-linq-where-expression) question about more info.

Comment: Ask, I have updated my answer to support dynamically building the where clause based on the property name.

Comment: Thanks alot, what if I have to add 2 conditions. Let say null or whitespace check?

Comment: I updated the answer. You don't really need to combine two conditions, just call the string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public IQueryable<TModel> Generate<TModel, TProperty>(Func<TModel, TProperty> propertyFunc, IQueryable<TModel> query)
{
    return query.Where(a => propertyFunc(a) != null);
}
```

It will be a more flexible solution than Dmitry.

Comment: I think, I wrote the question wrongly. The issue is I don't exactly which property I need to pass in Generate(m => m.Property2, query); I have only string value that I can pass. It might be Property1 or Property2 or Property3. Like Generate("property3", query);

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public IQueryable<MyModel> Generate(string property, IQueryable<MyModel> query)
{
    query = query.Where(a => EF.Property<string>(a, property) != null);
}
```

Reference: [EF.Property(Object, String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-5.0#examples)