# How to check for null and empty string in Exression.Constant?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I am using linq Expression to generate query but I am stuck on a point where I want to add null or empty check.
Here is the code:

```
var constant = Expression.Constant(null, typeof(object));
var comparison = Expression.Equal(field, constant);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyModel, bool>>(comparison, parameter);
```

Now I want to check for both null and empty in constant. How can I do that?

Comment: string.isNullOrEmpty?

Comment: I don't think I can use string.IsNullOrEmpty in Expression.Constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I answered in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715392/how-to-give-property-name-in-string-in-lambda-expression/52715689?noredirect=1#comment92361551_52715689).

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyModel), "x");
var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, nameof(MyModel.Property1));
var methodCall = Expression.Call(typeof(string), nameof(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace), null, body);
var nullOrWhiteSpaceComparison = Expression.Not(methodCall);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyModel, bool>>(nullOrWhiteSpaceComparison, parameter);
```

Use it as:

```
query.Where(lambda);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` or generate an `OrElse` expression. If in doubt, write the code in C# and look at the expression tree that the compiler generates. E.g.

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> expr = (str => str == null || str.Length == 0);
```

Then, inspect it in the debugger.

Comment: How can I use this expression in lamda then?